# boost mapped_file and page fault

Tags: mmap, memory-mapped-files, page-caching

I have done the following test using `boost::iostreams::mapped_file` and encountered some page fault (detected using `getrusage`). The page faults in step 4 are something I could not understand.

1. the file is in disk, the size is exactly 1 page (4096 bytes). I created `mapped_file` using mode `readwrite`
2. I mapped the file and read the first byte. This generated a page fault as expected.
3. I started another round the same as step 2. No page fault is observed, matches expectation
4. I then write one byte to it and saw one minor page fault, which I could not understand why.
5. I write another byte and no page fault is observed. Matches expectation again.

I think Step 3 already confirmed that the page is in physical memory. Then why did step 4 still generate a page fault? I only have some feeling that this might be related to copy-on-write, or related to `PRIVATE` vs `SHARED` mapping.

Can I assume that after step 2, the process has a virtual memory `V` that is mapped to the page cache `C` in the physical memory managed by the kernel? When writing to `V`, is `C` directly modified? Does this depends on whether `PRIVATE` or `SHARED` mapping is used?